# make div text disappear after 5 seconds using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need to make a div text disappear after x seconds of displaying it using an ajax call

can you help me on this please ?

thanks

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use [`empty()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/empty) to remove a `<div>` contents:

```
setTimeout(fade_out, 5000);

function fade_out() {
  $("#mydiv").fadeOut().empty();
}
```

assuming:

```
<div id="mydiv">
  ...
</div>
```

You can do this with an anonymous function if you prefer:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#mydiv").fadeOut().empty();
}, 5000);
```

or even:

```
var fade_out = function() {
  $("#mydiv").fadeOut().empty();
}

setTimeout(fade_out, 5000);
```

The latter is sometimes preferred because it pollutes the global namespace less.

Comment: working fine BUT i cannot recall that div again .. i need to remove the div content text while keeping the div itself for new use ... thanks

Comment: then remove the call to empty() and just do the fadeOut()

Comment: I want to Give This Mydiv To Many Div. It's Not working with other div. only effect one div at a time. any solution.

Answer (score 7):

You can try the `.delay()`

```
$(".formSentMsg").delay(3200).fadeOut(300);
```

call the div set the delay time in milliseconds and set the property you want to change, in this case I used .fadeOut() so it could be animated, but you can use .hide() as well.

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 1):

You would need to set something like setTimeout('$("#id").fadeOut("slow")', 5000) but other than that it depends on what the rest of your code looks like

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $.doTimeout(5000, function() { 
        $('#mydiv').fadeOut(); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: What's the deal with $.doTimeout? Is that from a plugin, or part of the core?

Comment: See http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/, in this case I'd just use window.setTimeout thought, not really worth the cost of a plugin for something this simple

Answer (score 1):

You may need to display div text again after it has disappeared.
This can be done in 1 line.

```
$('#div_id').empty().show().html(message).delay(3000).fadeOut(300);
```

Answer (score 1):

This Answer is *without* **jQuery**, you can just grab your `element` and know its `index` position.

Then use it in the `div` below. I will be your div's index number in dom.

```js
    const div = document.querySelectorAll('div');
    setTimeout(() => {
        div[i].textContent = '';
    }, 3000);
```