# How to make text not last long in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am new here, so if this is on the wrong forum, please tell me.

I was just wondering how to make some text in HTML that only lasts for... let's say 3 seconds and then it just disappears.

If I need to I can use JavaScript.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes You are on right forum.. But this forum requires some effort should be shown by user. So if you tried anything then please post here.

Comment: yeah.... but i don't really have a clue how to do it. I know HTML and a bit of JavaScript and I am really good at Python... But I just don't have a clue how to do this...

Comment: if using jquery refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911290/make-div-text-disappear-after-5-seconds-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `css3`.

```
.fadeout {
    -webkit-transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: that doesn't really do anything, though. (i know i sound like a newbie.)

Comment: You add @hkpeprah css code to your css style sheet or your <style> tag.

Now you append your text to the dom with the class fadeout
    $( "document" ).append( "<p class='fadeout'>Test</p>" );